# how to pass model property to javascript function without @html.Raw

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a View where I am doing a foreach loop:

```
List<myModel> MyModelList

@foreach (MyModel item in Model.MyModelList)
{

}
```

and in the script tag:

```
<script >
    $(document).ready(fucntion(){
        var myJsclassINstance = new myjsClass('JSON.Encode(@Model.MyModelList)')
    });
 </script>
```

How can I get the value into the js function without using `@Html.Raw()`? (with `@Html.Raw()` it is working).

Comment: Why without `@Html.Raw`?

Comment: requirement what to do

Comment: Hi shaswatatripathy, correct me if am wrong, if you just want to take the property of the model in the java script function.you can just take  model property using @ keyword right? then why you need @html.raw and all. please clarify if am wrong

Comment: its not working with only @Model.MyModelList